# printing numbers as a rectangle with nested for loops in c++

Tags: c++, loops, shapes

I am a beginner in programming.

I am currently writing a code that takes the number 1 to 9 of rows and columns from the user. for single digits, there should be a "0"

the output should look like this:

```
Type a row number between 1 and 9: 3
Type a column number between 1 and 9:7
01 02 03 04 05 06 07
08 09 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

This is the code i currently have:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    int r,c,i,j,n,k;
    cout<<"Type a row number between 1 and 9: ";
    cin>>r;
    while (r<1 || r>9){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 9.";
        cin>>r;
    }
    cout<< "Type a column number between 1 and 9: ";
    cin>>c;
    while (c<1 || c>9){
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 9.";
        cin>>c;
    }

    n=r*c;

    for(k=0; k<n; k++){
    }

    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }       
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've added validity statements for the users.

This outputs:

```
Type a row number between 1 and 9: 3
Type a column number between 1 and 9:7
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

I can't figure out the 0 and how to implement the numbers into the rectangle.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, just change your output loop to:

```
int counter = 1;

for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        cout << counter << " ";
        ++counter;
    }       
    cout << endl;
}
```

If you would like to avoid the extra local variable you can also just do:

```
cout << (i*c + j + 1) << " ";
```

I would prefer the explicit version using `counter` as it makes it obvious what you're doing and you can easily switch the order of the loops/output if desired.

Comment: That solves the value increment; you may as well take a stab at "...for single digits, there should be a `"0"` as well.